# how to have 2 destination in 1 form using button and get the POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

- I have 2 buttons in 1 form
- in 1st button it can pass values into another page using `REQUEST`
- but in 2nd button i want again pass values to another page using `REQUEST`
- the problem is when i click the second button the destination is on the destination of 1st button
- i have read some answers, they say i need to change the action using `javascript`
- I've tried their suggestion but it doesn't work for me.

  `<form action="first_btn_destination.php">
  $data = "data1";
  <input type="submit" name="first_btn" id="first_btn">
  <input type="submit" name="second_btn" id="second_btn">
  </form>`
- how can i change the action using javascript and pass the value.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do such a thing without javascript. One way to do it is to change `action` attribute of the form using javascript when you click on a form and submit it manually.

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission) to see how you can prevent your form from submitting on button clicking.

UPDATE:

The following code shows you how to change `action` using javascript before submitting.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="submit" name="first_btn" id="first_btn" onclick="modifyAction('http://google.com')">
    <input type="submit" name="second_btn" id="second_btn" onclick="modifyAction('http://yahoo.com')">
</form>
<script>
    var modifyAction = function(action) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').action = action;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of possible without javascript, in that they could visit the first page but never now it... If you can edit the first page, (where they go with first_btn and form action url) and it is a php page, you can test if the value of second_btn is set. Then, if it is set, you could use [php header to redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

```
<? 
if($_GET['second_btn'] || $_POST['second_btn']){
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/second_btn_page.php');
    exit;
}?>
```

This would bring the user to the second page in a way that is invisible to the end user. Note that php's header function needs to be placed high enough in your code such that *nothing at all* has been output to the browser, or it won't work.

Comment: why would you wanna redirect when it is possible to do it without it?

Comment: I've used a set up like this for a couple of reasons... It's simple since it's one language (so if Paul was familiar / comfortable with php, but not JavaScript, it might provide an alternative that was comfortable to work with). It is quite flexible. If you need to update a data base, or php session variables, that is of course easy. Works without JavaScript, which while not a concern these days, you never know... On balance, probably JavaScript is the way to go in this example, but it's nice to have options and it is something I have used, figured it's worth mentioning?